# How to use a bold font in subsections in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, bold

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Cambiar la fuente a Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
%PARA COMENTAR VARIAS LINEAS
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\contentsname{\centering CONTENIDO\par\bigskip \begin{flushright}
{\textrm P\'ag.}
\end{flushright}}
\tableofcontents

\begin{absolutelynopagebreak}
\portada






\begin{center}
\section{DESCRIPCIÓN DEL OBJETO Y SU CONTEXTO}
\end{center}

Como tal el objeto utilizado es una cámara del tipo ojo de pez (gran angular), la cual capturará imágenes en la cafetería de la UAO, con el objetivo de que mediante una aplicación desarrollada en Netbeans, las mismas puedan ser llevadas a una base de datos para hacer un procesamiento mediante redes neuronales artificiales (RNA) y de esta manera entregar el nivel de ocupación por parte de personas en la cafetería. Posteriormente se visualizará en la aplicación el estado actual, a su vez de que se almacenará en una base de datos los resultados del procesamiento. Las imágenes resultantes del proceso de extracción de características mediante la RNA serán almacenadas en formato Base64 en MySQL.

\end{absolutelynopagebreak}




\begin{center}
\section{ADQUISICIÓN DE DATOS}
\end{center}

Los datos se recolectan con la cámara ojo de pez la cual estará ubicada en el segundo piso de cafetería para capturar imágenes del primer piso de la misma, la cámara capturará la imagen cada cierto tiempo, sin embargo solo se realizará el procesado de la captura cuando se le solicite al sistema mediante un botón. El resultado del procesado se almacena en Base64 en MySQL en una base de datos que se le denominó monitoreo, y dentro de una tabla denominada cafetería con la siguiente información; identificador de consultas (NC) con auto\_increment, número de la cámara o identificación de la cámara, imagen capturada post-procesada, nivel de ocupación, fecha y hora del procesamiento de la imagen. 

\begin{center}
\subsection{HARDWARE Y SOFTWARE REQUERIDOS}
\end{center}


Respecto a los requerimientos de software, por el momento tenemos:

\begin{itemize}
    \item XAMPP.
    \item MySQL. 
    \item NetBeans. 
    \item Google Colab.
    \item Google Drive.
\end{itemize}

El hardware requerido es el siguiente:

\begin{itemize}
    \item Cámara ojo de pez.
    \item Computador. 
\end{itemize}
\subsection{example}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample]

I need to make the subsection numbers bold and and change the titles to capital letters in the table of contents. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Your image by itself isn't very helpful, since we don't know anything about how you are generating your table of contents. Please edit your question to include a compilable example document. It doesn't need to be big,  but it should begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}.

Comment: And do you want only the numbers of subsections to be bold, or both the numbers and the titles?

Comment: I need both things

Comment: This document is for my thesis and it is so long to insert there.

Comment: No, we don't need to see the whole thing.  Remove everything except some sample text.

Comment: I've removed a lot of irrelevant things  to make an example document. It's not completely minimal, but I think it shows the problem.

Comment: I have changed the description.

Answer (score 3):

Whole toc in bold with this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}

{
\bfseries
\tableofcontents
}

\section{ADQUISICIÓN DE DATOS}
\subsection{HARDWARE Y SOFTWARE REQUERIDOS}
\subsection[EXAMPLE]{example}
text
\end{document}
```

For not everything, but only subsections bold:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand\contentsname{\centering CONTENIDO\par\bigskip \begin{flushright}
{\textrm P\'ag.}
\end{flushright}}
\tableofcontents

%\begin{absolutelynopagebreak}
%\portada


%\begin{center}
\section{DESCRIPCIÓN DEL OBJETO Y SU CONTEXTO}
%\end{center}

Como tal el objeto utilizado es una cámara del tipo ojo de pez (gran angular), la cual capturará imágenes en la cafetería de la UAO, con el objetivo de que mediante una aplicación desarrollada en Netbeans, las mismas puedan ser llevadas a una base de datos para hacer un procesamiento mediante redes neuronales artificiales (RNA) y de esta manera entregar el nivel de ocupación por parte de personas en la cafetería. Posteriormente se visualizará en la aplicación el estado actual, a su vez de que se almacenará en una base de datos los resultados del procesamiento. Las imágenes resultantes del proceso de extracción de características mediante la RNA serán almacenadas en formato Base64 en MySQL.

%\end{absolutelynopagebreak}



%\begin{center}
\section{ADQUISICIÓN DE DATOS}
%\end{center}

Los datos se recolectan con la cámara ojo de pez la cual estará ubicada en el segundo piso de cafetería para capturar imágenes del primer piso de la misma, la cámara capturará la imagen cada cierto tiempo, sin embargo solo se realizará el procesado de la captura cuando se le solicite al sistema mediante un botón. El resultado del procesado se almacena en Base64 en MySQL en una base de datos que se le denominó monitoreo, y dentro de una tabla denominada cafetería con la siguiente información; identificador de consultas (NC) con auto\_increment, número de la cámara o identificación de la cámara, imagen capturada post-procesada, nivel de ocupación, fecha y hora del procesamiento de la imagen. 

%\begin{center}
\subsection{HARDWARE Y SOFTWARE REQUERIDOS}
%\end{center}


Respecto a los requerimientos de software, por el momento tenemos:

\begin{itemize}
    \item XAMPP.
    \item MySQL. 
    \item NetBeans. 
    \item Google Colab.
    \item Google Drive.
\end{itemize}

El hardware requerido es el siguiente:

\begin{itemize}
    \item Cámara ojo de pez.
    \item Computador. 
\end{itemize}
\subsection{example}
\end{document}
```